# Stacked plot from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, stacked

I would like to create a stacked bar plot from the following dataframe:

```
   VALUE     COUNT  RECL_LCC  RECL_PI
0      1  15686114         3        1
1      2  27537963         1        1
2      3  23448904         1        2
3      4   1213184         1        3
4      5  14185448         3        2
5      6  13064600         3        3
6      7  27043180         2        2
7      8  11732405         2        1
8      9  14773871         2        3
```

There would be 2 bars in the plot. One for RECL_LCC and other for RECL_PI. There would be 3 sections in each bar corresponding to the unique values in RECL_LCC and RECL_PI i.e 1,2,3 and would sum up the COUNT for each section. So far, I have something like this:

```
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)    
sub_df = df.groupby(['RECL_LCC','RECL_PI'])['COUNT'].sum().unstack()
sub_df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

However, I get this plot:

[image]

Any idea on how to obtain 2 columns (RECL_LCC and RECL_PI) instead of these 3?

Comment: Are all your dtypes numeric? You can do `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` to ensure the dtypes are ints/floats

Comment: Agree with @EdChum. Your code checks out on my side (I can plot it just fine).

Comment: thanks! that was needed, modified code to include the convert_objects statement. the plot still needs some work.

Comment: Should I post an answer?

Comment: Does your answer include fix for the plot too?

Comment: Sorry no, I just read your edit, really you should post 1 question at a time, anyway, what are you trying to plot? can you check if your groupby does what you want as I suspect it's not

Comment: sorry, I did want the plot, but was stopped by the error before that. If you post your answer, I will accept it, and open a new question. thanks!

Comment: I'll post an answer but I think you need to understand what is plotted, the values here show the variation in your values, as you have 3 groups at level RECL_LCC you will have 3 columns

Comment: I do understand the data, but not sure how to represent it in the groupby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem was that the dtypes were not numeric so no aggregation function will work as they were strings, so you can convert each offending column like so:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(int)
```

or just call `convert_objects` on the df:

```
df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Comment: thanks! How did you know that they were not numeric?

Comment: In your original post you had the error: `*** TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot` now the only way you could have an empty dataframe after performing the aggregation is if none of your columns were numeric

Comment: gotcha, makes sense now

Comment: I don't know how you created the df but usually you can specify the dtype when loading data or when creating the df

Comment: I was reading it using from_csv, that does not have a dtype, it seems like

Comment: @user308827 `from_csv` is ancient and not updated, use `read_csv`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv dtypes can be set by passing a dict to `dtype` param where key is column and value is the dtype